# 2D Game, calculate the value for transform.Rotate out of 2 vectors

Tags: math, unity-game-engine

first I wanna say I am really new to unity3d. I have done some tutorials and now I playing around a bit. So here is my problem. I have a 2D scene with a gravity source in the middle (lets say its a planet). I have a spaceship in his orbit. The gravity is simulated with:

```
var myVector = GameObject.Find("middle").transform.position - transform.position;
rigidbody2D.velocity += 0.2 * Time.deltaTime * myVector;
```

I can rotate the spaceship with:

```
if(Input.GetKey(moveLeft)) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * -turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
        //this value is something like (0, 0, -8)
    } 

    if(Input.GetKey(moveRight)) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        //this value is something like (0, 0, 8)
    }
```

What I want is that the spaceship automaticly rotates when it changes the angle to the planet. So that if it is in his orbit the same side allways looks forward. I have done a small sketch for that:
http://snag.gy/AGJMR.jpg
(The Arrow is the spaceship with his direction, it should rotate while the angle between the spaceship and the planet changes)

Basicly: when the spaceship flies around the planet 1 time it also makes a 360° rotation.

I have the old Vector (from spaceship to planet) saved and also have the actual vector:

```
var myVector = GameObject.Find("middle").transform.position - transform.position;
lastVector = myVector;
//for example:
myVector is (-1, 1, 0)
lastVector is (-1, -1, 0)
```

Out of this 2 value I should be able to get the value for transform.Rotate (something like (0, 0, 2). But I have no idea how I get there.

Comment: I cant open your sketch, can you upload an image instead?

Comment: Unity has a few tricks, and I know one for a case like this. If you want it the easy way, I can recommend you to put the spaceship as a child of the planet. Then rotating that planet will move the spaceship too and make it like your sketch. I got the inspiration from unity official tutorial.

Comment: @JayKazama I know what you mean, but I think you missunderstand me. My problem is im not the Math-Guy and never heard about eulerAngles. Anyway, I am halfway done. 'transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * angle);' does the trick. Now I just need the right sign for the angle

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty easy:

```
var angle = Vector3.Angle(lastVector, myVector);
var cross = Vector3.Cross(lastVector, myVector);
if(cross.z >0) {
    angle = -angle;
}
transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * angle);
```